# Send data from model signal post_save to view

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am connected to an API then I save all data coming to my DB, I have already setup the signals for that model's post_save.

How can I display all new data to my feed without the users needing to reload the page ?

I created a scheduler using apscheduler that pulls out the data from the API every specific time.

updater.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from news_updater import newsAPI

def start():
    print('sched start')
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(newsAPI.get_fxstreet_news, 'interval', minutes=1)
    scheduler.start()
```

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class NewsFilterConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'news_filter'

    def ready(self):
        from news_updater import updater
        updater.start()
```

and I added this to my models.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save
def save_article(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print('new article saved')


post_save.connect(save_article, sender=NewsArticles)
```

it's already printing the 'new article saved' everytime a new data comes in.

I also have setup a channel and is connected but I don't know how I can piece everything together

consumers.py

```
import asyncio
import json
from channels.consumer import AsyncConsumer
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async

from .models import NewsArticles

class NewsArticlesConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        print('connected', event)
        await self.send({
            'type': 'websocket.accept'
        })

        latest_news_obj = await self.get_latest_news()
        print(latest_news_obj)

        await self.send({
            'type': 'websocket.send',
            'text': "hello world"
        })

    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        print('received', event)

    async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        print('disconnected', event)

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_latest_news(self):
        return NewsArticles.objects.filter(is_new=True)[0]
```

Comment: You should post some example code that you have tried so far. A basic implementation could be some JS that continually polls an API that returns the latest data

Comment: @IainShelvington sorry and thank you for your comment. I just edited my post. I hope it helps you understand my issue better. I am fairly new to Django.